# Recover ext4 partition superblock `Free blocks count wrong for group #0`

Tags: ext4, troubleshooting, corruption, e2fsck

I have a broken ext4 partition which I want to recover. The problem occurred because of a sudden power loss. The partition is an encrypted luks partition. Opening the luks container works. Say I open it to `/dev/mapper/test`.

Then I am able to mount the partition like

```
mount -t ext4 -o sb=131072,ro /dev/mapper/test /mnt
```

Where 131072 is the location of the [superblock multiplied by 4](https://superuser.com/q/1137415/53616).

Then I can access the files (which I already backed up after the successful mount).

However if I try to [repair the superblock](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/) the following happens:

```
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/mapper/test 
e2fsck 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
/dev/mapper/test was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (23391, counted=280).
Fix<y>?
```

If I press `y` the same message `Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (23391, counted=280).` appears again and again (with another number at the end). I already pressed yes several times and then hold the `y` key down for a certain time.

Now I am looking for an advice what to do to repair the the partition. Is there an automatic way to answer `y` to this question so I don't have to hold the `y` key for an indefinite time? I could use the `-y` command line parameter, but then other questions would be also answered with yes.

Or should I do something else?

Comment: Did you unmount the partition before running`e2fsck`? Checking a mounted file system is always a bad idea.

Comment: Yes I did unmount it.

Comment: You might try adding `-vn` to your command line just to check out all the errors. Other than that you will probably need the `-y` flag to clear the errors.